# Splash screen Xcode progress bar

Tags: xcode, splash-screen

Hi  there is there any nice tutorial about progress bar and splash screen?

I can't figure out how to accomplish that. It would be great if you give some guide on how to show a splash screen with progress bar when the program loads up.

Thanks for your help
Cheers

Comment: I share this question, and am surprised it has been viewed nearly 5000 times yet nearly no one has said anything about it.

Answer (score -1):

You can create your own view controller with what ever you want and add it as a subview to your window for few seconds to show.